# Deleting a cognito user as admin

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
String userPoolId="testPoolID";
String username= "testuser";
String amazonAWSAccessKey="test access key";
String amazonAWSSecretKey="test secret key";
AdminDeleteUserRequest req = new AdminDeleteUserRequest();
req.setUsername(username);
req.setUserPoolId(userPoolId);
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey);   
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials); 
credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
req.setRequestCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider); 
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider provider = new AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient();
provider.adminDeleteUser(req);
```

This is the code snippet for deleting a user from cognito User pool. How we can delete a user from cogito without providing credentials using java ?

Answer (score 0):

- One way to do this would be to put this code in a lambda & expose it via API Gateway. Create another userpool for admins (its free!) & enable cognito userpool authorizers for your API. Now in your code, show a login screen (use Cognito's built-in UI) ,get the ID tokens and use this ID token while calling your API. This way your code will dynamically get tokens & so no hard-coded credentials.
- Another way would be to use Cognito Federated Identities but in this case no lambda + API Gateway is needed. Again, create a userpool for Admins & add this as an Auth Provider in a Cognito Identity Pool. Now, login to the Admin userpool, get an Id token, use this token in the login map for the IdentityPool & get temporary credentials using [GetCredentialsForIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html). Just make sure that the Auth role for the Cognito Identity Pool has appropriate permissions to perform userpool actions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its late, might be helpful for others who stumble on this.
If your code is in a lambda you can use the following code

```
AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
    .withRegion(region).build();
```

Note: Check if your lambda execution role is having access to cognito